# If statement doesn't execute

Tags: java, if-statement

I am creating a program that allows you to create a pie chart easily. In the method for removing a slice the if statement inside of a for loop doesnt execute and I cant figure out why this happens. Here is the removeSlice method:

```
public void removeSlice(Color color, float size, String displayText){
        int num = 0;
        System.out.println("Thing: " + color + " " + size + " " + displayText);
        for(int i = 0; i < slice.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("I: " + slice.get(i).color + " " + slice.get(i).size + " " + slice.get(i).text + " Current: " + i);
            if(slice.get(i).color == color && slice.get(i).size == size && slice.get(i).text.equals(displayText)){
                num = i;
                System.out.println("It Works");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(num);
        slice.remove(slice.get(num));
        totalSize -= size;
        --current;
    }
```

When trying to remove a slice the console output shows this

```
Thing: java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255] 100.0 Hey
I: java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0] 500.0 Hi Current: 0
I: java.awt.Color[r=255,g=153,b=153] 70.0 Hello Current: 1
I: java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255] 100.0 Hey Current: 2
I: java.awt.Color[r=153,g=153,b=0] 120.0 Hola Current: 3
0
```

as you see all of the values equal position 2's values in the ArrayList but still the if statement doesn't execute.

Comment: If you aren't using the `Color` constants, you will need to compare with `equals()`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1065197. Instead of `String` class, your problem is with `Color` class.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you should always use `equals` when comparing object references except for `enum`s since they are singleton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing colors with ==. Use equals instead. == checks if the objects refer to the same place in memory. You create two colors, but with the same content - then, you must use equals to check if the content match.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify   `slice.get(i).color == color` to   `slice.get(i).color.equals(color)`.

You should use `.equals()` method to compare color object.

```
if(slice.get(i).color.equals(color) && slice.get(i).size == size && slice.get(i).text.equals(displayText)){
                num = i;
                System.out.println("It Works");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the == issue for Color, exact equality comparison for float can give problems. It will work if the values being compared were produced by **exactly** the same calculation, or if all calculations involved are exact. If not, there may be different rounding error leading to a very small difference in values that would be equal in real number arithmetic.

Small integer-valued floats such as 100.0 do represent the integer exactly, so that is probably not your current problem, but it could give you problems with different numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As a Java Programmer, you should know about [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). Quite often this is what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

try to compare the different values with "equals", no with "=="

Answer (score 0):

You need to use equals() instead of == for the Color objects.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say because we can't see whole source code but I think that your problem is here "slice.get(i).color == color". With == you tests if both variables reference the same object.

You should consider to use slice.get(i).color.equals(color) and you need to also implement equals, hashCode methods on that object